# how to specify jar file path in files section to exec

Tags: inno-setup

i want to execute a Portnumber.jar file which contains Port class and append the output to a file.Port class is a java program to check whther the entered port is in use or not.8081 is the port through command line arguments.

```
[Files]    
source:"E:\creating.exe\innosetup\innosetupscripts\practice1\sourcefiles\TestPortnumber.jar";  DestDir: "{app}";

[Code]
....
var
 ResultCode: Integer;
 Result1:String ;
 begin

  if  Exec('cmd', '/c ""C:\Program Files\java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -cp Portnumber.jar    Port 8081 > E:\Test.txt"', '', SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
   begin
   Msgbox('success'+Result1,mbError, MB_OK);
   end
 else
  begin
  Msgbox('false'+Result1,mbError, MB_OK);
  Result:=False;
  end
 end;
```

1.how to specify the jar file  in exec command and
2.syntax for specifying the user entered port in the command

Comment: This approach is not a good way. What if the user won't have Java installed ? And if so, you will need to find the path to it since you can install it wherever you want. Btw. I'd be glad to meet someone who first came with executing `cmd` instead of the binary itself. If you know Winsock API a little bit, I can undelete the post I wrote for you for a while (before I finish it, which I can't guarantee when could be). It's missing almost only the decision part. All the prototypes are translated and tests passed. It's the most native way you can have... Would you like to see it ?

Comment: before this there is a setup to install java also in my program.I dont know about winsock API.Is using Winsock API is the better method to check if a port in use than calling jar file which contained java program to find whether port is in use or not?yes i would like to see

Comment: Definitely yes. It is native to Windows. That Java application will finally execute the same, just through its runtime.

Comment: Is there any solution with you for my problem